# How could I implement saving priority to the model in ORM and later getting object with the highest priority in view?

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm building application with Django but got a problem with django ORM .

We have a model related to some user. I later need to get all object of this model in view with the highest priority. So if I have to same objects, I need to get one with highest priority. How could I implement saving priority to database  and later getting object with the highest priority in view? It must must be so simple, but I have no idea

Answer (score 0):

In your **models.py** file, you can write something like this:

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):

    PRIORITY_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Low'),
        (1, 'Normal'),
        (2, 'High'),
    )

    priority = models.IntegerField(null=True,
                                   choices=PRIORITY_CHOICES,
                                   default=PRIORITY_CHOICES[0][0],)
```

In your **views.py** file, you can write something like this:

```
from .models import MyModel
from django.shortcuts import render

def my_view(request):
    context = {
        'details': MyModel.objects.order_by('-priority')
    }
    return render(request, 'my_template.html', context=context)
```

Writing **order_by('-priority')** indicates that we need to sort the details in descending order.

Append **my_view** to **urls.py** file and you're good to go.